# Delete original file after zipping it

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I am looping through a directory and zip the files in it. In the following code, I am adding the original file to a zipOutputStream, and then delete the file.
With the code below, I get the following exception:

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Desktop\test.zip' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at ZipFiles.zipFile(String fileToZip, ZipOutputStream oStream) in C:\Users\Desktop\CodeFile1.cs:line 34
   at ZipFiles.zipByFileSize(String dir) in C:\Users\Desktop\CodeFile1.cs:line 75
```

I understand that this exception occurs because the file is being zipped and I am deleting it at the same time? if so, how do I make sure that the zipping happens before the deleting?

Here is my code:

```
try
                {
                    using (ZipOutputStream oStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipPath)))
                    {
                        oStream.SetLevel(8); // 9 = highest compression
                        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        {
                            string fileToZip = sorted.ElementAt(j);
                            zipFile(fileToZip, oStream);


                            File.Delete(fileToZip);
                        }

                        oStream.Finish();
                        oStream.Close();
                    }


                    // limitIndex = i - 1;
                    startIndex = i - 1;
                    zipNumber += 1;
                    size = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
```

I am using the following libraries:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about running a second loop to do the deleting after you've done all of the zipping?

```
try
{
  using (ZipOutputStream oStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipPath)))
  {
    oStream.SetLevel(8); // 9 = highest compression
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        string fileToZip = sorted.ElementAt(j);
        zipFile(fileToZip, oStream);
    }

    oStream.Finish();
    oStream.Close();
  }

  // Delete the files now.
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
    string fileToZip = sorted.ElementAt(j);
    File.Delete(fileToZip);
  }


  // limitIndex = i - 1;
  startIndex = i - 1;
  zipNumber += 1;
  size = 0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me: as I was deleting the file in my "sorted" variable, the length of sorted changed. I found a work around: i check if a file is already in a zip file, then I delete the file in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure I don't have any open handles on the file I am using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` which only returns a string. Then I use the built-in `ZipArchiveExtension.CreateEntryFromFile` which doesn't leave a handle when it returns because I am able to delete it right away. I set attributes to normal because that ensures you don't get an access denied on delete, from an attribute.

```cs
using var archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, fileType, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    try
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));

        File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```